# Swapping disks between different systems

Tags: 14.04, swap, disk

I am going to swap my laptop's drive for my desktop's drive. Both run a 64bit 14.04 distro. My laptop has an Intel Celeron CPU while my desktop runs on a AMD A6 CPU What are some things that I need to know? Do I need to make any changes in any part of the OS or will linux kernel take care of swapping modules as necessary?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without complete HW specification, it is hard to tell precisely, but the most probable result is that Linux will handle this kind of things without problems.

What I would suggest installing on both systems before swapping disks are packages `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree`, because those contain firmwares to all network cards and similar stuff... Beware, the `-nonfree` package contains some closed source software (if you care about that)